# Command line DVD to ISO ripper

Tags: dvd, headless, archiving

I have an old XBOX with XBMC installed and I want to rip my dvd collection to my home server as ISO files so that I can watch them over the network. My server is headless (no monitor), so I need the software to run on Solaris, Linux or OpenBSD without X11 running.

Does such a magical tool exist? I've seen vobcopy, but does that only work on VOBs? Since XBMC supports DVD menus and everything as though it was a straight disc, I'd rather have my backup work exactly as it does without needing my DVD.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dd` to make a copy of the raw disc image.

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=/srv/storage/sometitle.iso bs=32M
```

Comment: Will there be any trouble with CSS, or will the ISO just carry that over with it? I'll give that a shot. If it works, I'm going to bang my head on the wall for not thinking of that.

Comment: Contrary to what Hollywood Industry wants to tell you, you don't need to crack CSS in order to make a low-level digital copy.

Comment: Well, doing a copy lead to I/O device error. The disc plays fine, did an oconv=noerror and it still died.

Comment: Is this just on that disc, or on every disc?

Comment: More info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4648620&postcount=4

Comment: Trying with "dd if=/dev/scd1 of=cd.iso conv=noerror,sync BS=32M" will report back when finished.

Comment: Yar! No luck. Disc copied but doesn't play. I can however extract files from the ISO. Comparing to a DVD Decryptor rip next.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out there's a piece of software called dvdbackup which will rip the entire DVD structure off the disc. I was able to build it on both OpenBSD (from ports) and Solaris 11 (with devel/gcc-3 package installed). It's not exactly what I wanted, so I'll need to inject these files into an ISO afterwards using mkisofs or something. If it works, I'll post the complete process.